# How to update object with Boost Serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization, boost-serialization

Say we had a class with `std::map<string, string>` in it. Say we had an instance of it with data like `[Jon : Smith; Sara : O'Connel]`. We  serialized it and puted into archive. Now we created another instance of it with such map contents `[Jon : AnotherSmith; Brian : Gor]`.  We  serialized it and puted into archive. Now we have 2 archives!) I wonder how we could deserialize tham 2 into one object instance, how we could set data from which archive overrites which say we want to get: `[ Sara : O'Connel; Jon : AnotherSmith; Brian : Gor]`?

Answer (score 0):

Write a class that holds the map and serialize that instead.
in your serialize function (or load/save), you can then copy the map serialization code from boost and customize it to implement your overwriting requirements.